# Coding the slideshow

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is what i have :

HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>JQuery demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/slider.js"></script>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="slider">
        <img class="image" src="images/image1.jpg" alt="image"/>
        <div class="title">Title1</div>
        <div class="bulletContainer">
            <div class="bullet active"></div>
            <div class="bullet"></div>
            <div class="bullet"></div>
            <div class="bullet" style="clear: right;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="caption">Subtitle1</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body { 
    font-family:Tahoma;
    background-color: gray; 
}
#slider {
    width: 733px;
    height: 395px;
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
    background-image: url("../images/billboards-bg.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#slider > .image {
    margin: 10px 6px 2px 6px;
}
#slider > .title {
    float:left;
    color: #5D5B5B;
    margin-left: 7px;
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: bold;
}  
#slider > .bulletContainer {
    float:right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 7px;
}
#slider > .caption {
    clear:both;
    margin-left: 7px;
    padding-top: 2px;
}
#slider > .bulletContainer > .bullet {
    width:20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-image:;
    margin: 2px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url("../images/billboard-pager.png");
    background-position:  0 0;
} 
#slider > .bulletContainer > .bullet:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-position:  0 -20px;
}
#slider > .bulletContainer > .bullet.active {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-position:  0 -40px;
}
```

And at last the main thing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".bullet").click(function() {
        $(".bullet.active").attr("class", "bullet");
        $(this).attr("class", "bullet active");
        setContent($(".bullet").index(this));
    });
    var images = ["images/image1.jpg", 
                  "images/image2.jpg", 
                  "images/image3.jpg",
                  "images/image4.jpg"];
    var titles = ["Title1", "Title2", "Title3", "Title4"];
    var subtitles = ["Subtitle1", "Subtitle2", "Subtitle3", "Subtitle4"]

    function setContent(index) {
        $(".image").fadeOut("fast", function() {
            $(this).attr("src", images[index]);
            $(".image").fadeIn("fast");
        });
    }
});
```

The thing is i want to change titles and subtitles(caption) same when to change picture but i dont have a slightest idea how to do that.

Comment: Change Title1 and Subtitle1 to the text you want to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/ubfLe/

Change the function `setContent`:

```
function setContent(index)
{
    $(".image").fadeOut("fast", function()        
    {
        $(this).attr("src", images[index]);
        $(".title").html(titles[index]);
        $(".caption").html(subtitles[index]);
        $(".image").fadeIn("fast");
    });
}
```

Comment: can it be done that each picture of these is a link to other page ?

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ubfLe/1/ ...
But onload you won't have an anchor tag around image

Comment: yes, but i wasnt specific enough. The thing is i want to each picture has its own page link. I cant get from the code u sent how to change that ?

Comment: Yes you can ...create an array for the links...like you did for image src

Comment: ive put for images var images, what do i put for links if i put them in $(".image")  ?

Answer (score 0):

Id switch the fadein and fadeout speed to milliseconds rather than fast or slow.

Lets pretend you use the following...

```
$(".image").fadeOut(1000, function()        
    {
        $(this).attr("src", images[index]);
        $(".image").fadeIn(1000);
    });
```

Then, you could make a code that checks for the index after the trigger and replace the title/subtitle with the new one with that index.

```
$(".bullet").click(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".title").html(titles[$.inArray($(".image").attr("src"), images)]);
    }, 1000);
});
```

That's just me though. I didn't test this because I'm a little strapped for time but ill clean it up later if it doesn't work. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: ok ill give it a try, let me ask u a question while we talk about it. Tell me what do i have to add so the pics are sliding just on page load?

Comment: hmmm. If I understand your goal correctly, you can replace the $(".bullet").click with $(document).ready

Though if you did that, I recommend you making it a function instead. Then you could call the function on $(document).ready and ALSO can put it on a trigger as well (like $(".bullet").click)

I made a fiddle for you to help.
[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hTZWq/1/)

I made it so that it fires on load(once) and then allows you to change it on click. I also threw in a comment that shows you how to make it fire continously after a timed period but look up clear setInterval if you do that.

Comment: this is a bit confusing to me, the thing is i want this to slide on its own. Not just when i click the button

Comment: Try this...
[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hTZWq/2/)
I set this up to rotate through the images on its own at 2 and a half seconds~
I hope it helps.

Comment: yes i can see, i want to add with this code ihave for now. So ill try add and see if it works

Comment: it doesnt work for me, because i want the allready all functions i have + the change of slide. When i put the change function it doesnt work for me i dont know maybe i do something wrong

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hTZWq/2/ the funny thing is that buttnos when i put them here (they are invisble on right side because i didnt put the background of picture) perfectly work, but on my computer they dont ? i dont get the idea

Comment: and the thing is it is always rotating the same picture, not swaping but it is obviusly coz i didnt put 'function change(){
    if (index == 3){
        index = 0;
    }
    $(".picture").fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $(".picture").html(image[index++]);
        $(".picture").fadeIn(1000);
    });
    
}' but i dont know where to put it

Comment: I think you forgot to update the fiddle or copied the wrong url. You shared the same one I sent you. There were no buttons.
I just pieced this together for you.
[fiddle bro](http://jsfiddle.net/hTZWq/4/)
It includes a next button and a rotating image, title, subtitle.
I also threw in a handler to prevent it from just rotating the last image. I ALSO made it so that it counts your array so you dont have to increase its limits before it loops back to the beginning.
It still needs a clear interval code in there, but you should be able to find that. Should work with your code.

Comment: ok lets say i use your code witch is perfectly ok, how do i implement one more thing i have to put on each picture it is a link on some random page i want?

Comment: Wrap the div that holds your image in an <a class="links" href="whatever"> and then just add in a line that changes the href into the changing function. eg: $(".links").attr("href", links[index])
dont forget your array with the links in it.